# convert mysql subquery into codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, subquery

I am not able to convert subquery of mysql into codeigniter form.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM plo
WHERE PLO_id IN (SELECT PLO_id FROM plo_data WHERE subj_id = '221' )
```

Comment: Can I know which error you are getting  ?

Comment: I got the answer thank you so much...here is the query

Comment: ```$this->db->select('PLO_id')->from('plo_data')->where('subj_id',221);
  $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();
 

   return $this->db->select('*')
         ->from('plo')
         ->where("PLO_id IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE)
         ->get()
   ->result();```

Comment: Nopes i have added answer in my comment

Comment: Note that 221 is likely to be an integer, not a string, so the inverted commas are unwelcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `plo` WHERE `PLO_id` IN (SELECT `PLO_id` FROM `plo_data` WHERE `subj_id` ='221' ) ")
```

To convert your mysql query to codeigniter query.

Comment: Thank you... How can i give you like for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I can put your sub query into where

`$this->db->select("*")->from("plo");
$this->db->where("PLO_id IN (SELECT PLO_id FROM plo_data WHERE subj_id ='221')", NULL, FALSE);`